# ajax and php newsletter signup form

Tags: php, jquery

I'm building a form that uses ajax and php to validate an email address that a user has submitted. I'm about intermediate when it comes to php but with ajax i'm afraid I'm a novice.

I've done all the php and know it will work fine, problem is how do I make the ajax process the php script, currently I have created a function in ajax called completeSignup(); and it looks as:

```
function completeSignup() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#completeform").fadeOut(400, function(){
            $(this).before('<span class="done">All done! We will be in     touch.</span>');
        });
    }, 1100);
}
```

How do include the php script inside the function and keep it all on the same page?

Thanks

Comment: Look at JQuery's [xhr.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Comment: "How do include the php script inside the function" — You don't. You have some JavaScript to make an HTTP request and a separate piece of PHP to receive and process the request. Before that you forget about Ajax and make it work with a regular form submission, *then* you [enhance it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) to use Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing an ajax request anywhere. When using jquery you can do ajax queries using methods like `post()` or `ajax()`. if you give a look at the documentation by jquery, you will find loads of examples on how to do an ajax query with/without sending data to a php file.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

check the examples..

just a basic example here..

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "some.php",
data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

some.php file will contain your php logic. just for test purpose, `echo` something in that file and `die`. You will understand the whole thing in a better way then.